# Solving the equation $2x^2-\left(4x-7\right)\sqrt{x-1}-5x+4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quartics

> Solve the equation $$2x^2-\left(4x-7\right)\sqrt{x-1}-5x+4=0$$

Here is my work:

$$2x^2-5x+4=(4x-7)\sqrt{x-1}$$
$$2(x-1)^2-(x-1)+1=(4(x-1)-3)\sqrt{x-1}$$
Using the substitution $\sqrt{x-1}=t$,
$$2t^4-t^2+1=t(4t^2-3)$$
$$2t^4-4t^3-t^2+3t+1=0$$
Here I plugged in some natural numbers like $1,2,3$ but neither of them worked. So I don't know how to factor the polynomial to find the values of $t$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says your  last equation can be written as $$(t^2 - t - 1) (2 t^2 - 2 t - 1) = 0$$

Comment: The equations seem to be correct, so just factor the last expression.

Comment: Golden ratio satisfies the equation in 't'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using substitution to get rid of a square root is a great approach.  It's almost always better than squaring the equation.  Well done!

An additional trick is if the resulting equation looks unpleasant, don't replace *all* the $x$ with $t^2+1$.  Just replace the square root and leave the rest of the $x$s be.

Since it's not likely that anybody will ever ask you to solve a quartic equation the hard way, look for ways to then combine your equation with $t^2 = x - 1$ to create factoring opportunities.

$$2x^2 - 4xt + 7t - 5x + 4 = 0$$

Complete the square $2x^2 - 4xt$ by adding $2t^2 - 2x + 2=0$ and the equation becomes

$$2x^2 - 4xt + 2t^2 + 7t - 7x + 6=0$$

or

$$2(t-x)^2 + 7(t-x) + 6 = 0$$

This is now a quadratic for $t-x$ and the rest is simple.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 2):

What you did is fine. Now, let\begin{align}p(t)&=2t^4-4t^3-t^2+3t+1\\&=2\left(t^4-2t^3-\frac12t^2+\frac32t+\frac12\right)\end{align}and let $r(t)$ be the depressed quartic of $t^4-2t^3-\frac12t^2+\frac32t+\frac12$, that is\begin{align}\left(t+\frac12\right)^4-2\left(t+\frac12\right)^3-\frac12\left(t+\frac12\right)^2+\frac32\left(t+\frac12\right)+\frac12&=t^4-2t^2+\frac{15}{16}\\&=\left(t^2-\frac54\right)\left(t^2-\frac34\right),\end{align}since the roots of the quadratic equation $T^2-2T+\frac{15}{16}=0$ are $\frac34$ and $\frac54$. So,\begin{align}p(t)&=2r\left(t-\frac12\right)\\&=2(t^2-t-1)\left(t^2-t-\frac12\right).\end{align}

Comment: What is a "depressed quartic" please?

Comment: A depressed quartic is a quartic polynomial such that the coefficient of the cubic term is $0$. Mare generally, a depressed polynomial is a polynomial with degree $n$ such that the coefficient of the term with degree $n-1$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

> $2t^4-4t^3-t^2+3t+1=0$

Alt. hint: $\;\;\displaystyle
2t^4-4t^3\color{red}{+2t^2-2t^2}-t^2+3t+1 = \underbrace{2t^2(t-1)^2-3t(t-1)+1}_{\small{\displaystyle 2u^2-3u+1=(u-1)(2u-1)}}
$